# Using the momentum-space definition of the position operator in position space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, operators, momentum

For the position operator $\hat X$:

$\hat X \rightarrow x$ in position space

$\hat X \rightarrow i \frac{\partial}{\partial k_x}$ in momentum space

**Question:
Can $\hat X \rightarrow i \frac{\partial}{\partial k_x}$ be used in position space?**

Example: If $\Psi(x)=e^{-ikx}$ then both representations of $\hat X$ yield $\hat X\ | \Psi(x)>=x\ |\Psi(x)> $.

*Edit: As I've gotten a better understanding, it seems that the $i \frac{\partial}{\partial k_x}$ representation of $\hat X$ can be used in position space but only for specific functions?*

---

*Background on why I want to do this:*

The matrix element for the band-to-band tunneling of electrons from the valence band (VB) to the conduction band (CB) of a semiconductor is given by

(1)   $M =<\Psi_{CB}\ | \ q\phi(x) \  |\ \Psi_{VB}>$,

where $q\phi(x)$ is the potential along the tunneling path and $\Psi$ is the wavefunction in the CB and VB. ($\Psi=u_k(r)f_k(r)$, where $u$ is the Bloch function and $f$ is the envelope wavefunction.) Assuming a constant electric field ($F$) across the tunneling region,

(2)   $M =<\Psi_{CB}\ | \ qF\hat X \  |\ \Psi_{VB}>$.

Eq. (1) above matches Eq. (25) from [Schenk et al.](http://doi.org/10.1002/pssb.2221540240):

> [image: Schenk's paper]

Expressing $\hat X$ as $ i \frac{\partial}{\partial k_x}$ (shown in Eq. (26) in Schenk), allows the matrix element to be written in the form of Eq. (27), which is convenient for comparison to matrix elements of other potentials.

*Reference*: A. Schenk, M. Stahl, and H.-J. Wünsche, “Calculation of Interband Tunneling in Inhomogeneous Fields,” phys. stat. sol. (b), vol. 154, no. 2, pp. 815–826, Aug. 1989.

Answer (score 4):

> $\hat{X} = i\partial_{k_x}$ in momentum space

is wrong. The left hand side is an operator, the right hand side is the *representation* of an operator *when acting on functions*, taken with respect to the scalar product with the basis $|\ p\rangle$. In particular we have
$$
\langle x\,|\,\hat{x}\,|\,\phi\rangle = x\phi(x)
$$
and
$$
\langle p\,|\,\hat{x}\,|\,\phi\rangle = i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial k_x}\phi(p).
$$
As you can see the two above are different things, as they arise after taking scalar products with different basis elements.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I completely agree. I'm still trying to understand how they go from $e\phi(x)$ [which equals $eF\hat x$] in Eq. (25) to it's representation as $i \frac{\partial}{\partial k_x}$ in Eq. (26) given that everything is in position space. Any ideas?